# Which is more correctly "should" or "can't"

Tags: sentence-meaning, modal-verbs

> Why are you late? You must have taken a taxi.

I know that the mistake is "must", but I'm confused whether to put "should" or "can't". 
 
Which one is more correctly?

> Why are you late? You should have taken a taxi.

> Why are you late? You can't have taken a taxi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to describe a recommended behavior, you should use **should**:

> Why are you late? You **should** have taken a taxi.

The use of "**can't**" will render a sentence that indicates your belief:

> You can't have taken a taxi! (Meaning: I stongly believe that you did not take a taxi)

If your goal is to indicate a recommended behavior and still somehow use **can**, you might modify the sentence a bit:

> Why are you late? **Couldn't** you have taken a taxi?  (Meaning: I believe that you had the option of taking a taxi, and I'm amazed that you did not take a taxi)

Comment: In your opinion, Which is most correctly?

Comment: @MohamedMagdy - In my opinion, the best option is "You should have taken a taxi".